# Difference in Difference econometric specification for multiple treatment(no treatment(control group), low treatment, high treatment)

Tags: difference-in-difference

My treatment variable (Di) includes three groups. Group 1 with no treatment(control group); and, Group 2 and Group 3 with different level (intensity) of treatment.like technology adoption: partially adopting and fully adopting. Group 2 low level of treatment (consumption) and Group 3 with high level of treatment (consumption of …) or like that.
 I have two period panel data set. I want to see the program effect (impact) through difference-in-difference method. This deviate from the common binary treatment case of group having the treatment and group having no treatment. How then I could specify the regression framework for such case? Any helpful material. I have been browsing in google but can't find one.

Comment: Maybe see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99140/difference-in-difference-in-differences-estimator

Answer (score 2):

If your measure of treatment is continuous, you could estimate

$Y_{it} = \alpha + \beta_1 D_i + \beta_2 Post_t + \delta (D_i*Post_t) + \epsilon_{it}$

Then the effect of moving up the treatment intensity is $\beta_1 + \delta$.

If the measure of treatment is discrete, just include indicator variables for each level of treatment, a period indicator, and all interactions.

$Y_{it} = \alpha + \beta_1 D_{i2} +  \beta_2 D_{i3} + \beta_3 Post_t + \delta_1 D_{i2}*Post_t + \delta_2 D_{i3}*Post_t + \delta_3 D_{i2}*D_{i3}*Post_t  + \epsilon_{it}$

Now, $\delta_3$ gives the effect of any treatment relative to the control group, $\delta_2$ gives the effect of treatment group 3 relative to the control group, and $\delta_1$ gives the effect of treatment group 2 relative to the control group.

Comment: gannawag, thank you so much! any recommendation for further reading..? Any one else who can recommend documents worked on this type of approach?

Comment: Great appreciation so far.
Suppose my outcome variable (Yi) is milk yield (continuous) and treatment variable (Di) is categorical (dairy technology adoption= no adoption, partial and full). 
• In δ3Di2∗Di3∗Postt, what do you mean by any treatment?
• What can be said about group 1(the control group)?
• Can I find any reference for such kind of work at least to refer to and for better understanding?
• Can I get any STATA commands or do files?
• Email: melkamtw@gmail.com
Stay Blessed!

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. If the treatment is of varying intensity, we expect people in group 3 to also be in group 2, and hence the interaction term is exactly the same as the delta_3 term.

Comment: @hrrrrrr5602 You're referring to the second equation, correct? Agreed, something appears to be off if we include every level of treatment and all pairwise interactions. You could run this `y ~ post*low + post*high`, where the "no treatment group" is the reference group. However, I'm sure if we tried this `y ~ post*low + post*high + post*low*high`, then we would find singularities; the triple interaction should be dropped if I am not mistaken, and even the interaction between the two treatments. Any recommendations on how this could be improved?